# L'expression « jouer du violon » : que veut-elle dire et est-elle négative?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

Une de mes amis une fois m'a donné des conseils pour bien se préparer avant un entretien d'embauche, disant qu'il ne faut pas **jouer du violon** à l'employeur.

J'imagine que ça veut dire qu'il faut seulement dire la vérité, ou bien il ne faut pas exagérer nos expériences ou maîtrises...

Que signifie exactement cette expression et a-t-elle (toujours) un sens négatif?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jouer du violon* signifie plutôt chercher à émouvoir artificiellement, essayer d'attendrir quelqu'un par de fausses histoires. Dans un entretien d'embauche, jouer du violon à l'employeur consisterait à lui raconter combien votre vie est difficile, que vous avez une famille nombreuse à nourrir, que sans cet emploi, vous allez vous retrouver à la rue, que votre emploi actuel est horrible, etc. On peut aussi dire ironiquement *Sortez les violons* pour critiquer quelqu'un qui cherche à émouvoir avec opportunisme ou avec peu de tact.

Pour dire qu'on ment par exemple sur ses compétences ou son expérience, il y a une expression très proche: *jouer du pipeau*, un *pipeau* étant une petite flûte (dans le film français *Les Poupées russes* par exemple, il y a des scènes très drôles où le personnage principal ment à son banquier ou à son éditeur, et on voit à chaque fois son double imaginaire arriver derrière lui et se mettre à jouer littéralement du pipeau).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_02AWx2D74

Comment: Je pense que ça fait référence aux films mélo-dramatiques, quand une musique larmoyante (souvent un violon) accompagne les scènes les plus déchirantes.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication très détaillée et pour le nom du film. Tous ces expressions semblent être négative